# Invalid vote count in moderator election

Tags: bug, moderator-election

The vote sum is incorrect in moderator election. I'm not sure if everyone can see the vote counts, but even if not, it might be unfair for certain candidates. A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Could you check what's wrong with it, please? We all know that the vote sum can affect voters and as such it might be unfair.

Comment: Caching, probably? Either that or truncating to 0 for candidates with negative scores.

Comment: Candidates with negative scores display as 0.

Comment: Not in the past 2 elections you haven't @Vogel.

Comment: @Vogel612 he's right. The only negative score you'll see is -1 on candidates with "0" you've voted down.

Comment: @CoolGuy, thanks! I'm deleting this one in 3..2..1.. Hm, I cannot...

Comment: Why? Because there is an upvoted answer?

Comment: @CoolGuy, I got it. A popup message told me so. What I don't like is that my question was closed by Community♦ when I used that self-duplicate-agree button (I know, I know, that's the topic for the new question...).

Comment: @TLama take a time to read the tooltip when hovering on the Community user: "*This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote.*", it's clear enough that you agree to self-close as duplicate :)

Comment: @Andrew, I missed that, but it's not fair. It was me who closed it, not Community♦ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Candidates with negative scores are shown as 0 (or -1, if you've voted them down as well). But the real score is hidden for various reasons.

If you have the "Show vote counts" privilege, you can see the real scores (as you've already observed).

Comment: And the reason can be seen here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135576/election-primary-vote-count-is-no-lower-than-1

Comment: _"If you have the "Show vote counts" privilege, you can see the real scores"_ Actually, I can click the scores for the vote breakdown with only 254 rep. I'm assuming either that's a bug, or it's enabled only on the voting screen.